# Why WebStorm show errors in gql query inside apollo object in Vue component or .grapgql files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, webstorm, vue-apollo

I have a problem with WebStorm syntax highlighting. I created valid GraphQL query which works on localhost app but WebStorm says that

> unknown field "familyMembers" on object type "Query"

and highlights the whole query in red.

I am really confused but maybe I should change something inside `apollo.config.js` - if yes please tell me what.

HelloWorld.vue

```
<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
export default {
  apollo: {
    familyMembers: gql `
    query familyMembers {
        familyMembers {
            id
            firstName
            lastName
        }
    }`
  },
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>
```

apollo.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    client: {
        service: {
            name: 'vav',
            // URL to the GraphQL API
            url: 'http://localhost:4000',
        },
        // Files processed by the extension
        includes: [
            'src/**/*.vue',
            'src/**/*.js',
        ],
    },
};
```

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok so I figured out how to do this you do not need `apollo.config.js` you have to create .graphqlconfig in which you will declarate local schema path and endpoint url like that:

```
{
  "name": "Untitled GraphQL Schema",
  "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "Default GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "http://localhost:4000",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
        },
        "introspect": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put this `schema.graphql` file and what is the contents of it?

Comment: @martins16321 you have to create this file in the root of your project. I have also added integration docs to vue-appolo documentation. You can take a look on that: https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#webstorm

Comment: is there an example of what the `schema.graphql` file needs to look like? What content do I put inside of it?

Comment: Check GraphQL docs: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/